# Continuous function defined on a circle

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, analysis

Suppose $f$ is a continuous real function on $\Bbb T=\{z\in \Bbb C:|z|=1\}$ such that $f^2(z)=f(z)$ and $f(1)=0$,can we conclude that $f$ is a constant function?

Comment: Is this $f(z)\cdot f(z)=f(z)$ or $f(f(z))=f(z)$?

Comment: $f(z)\cdot f(z)=f(z)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, we can conclude that. Because $(f(z))^2=f(z)\implies f(z)=0 \text{ or } f(z)=1$. Now if $f$ takes both of the values, let $\theta = min\{arg(z)|f(z)=1\}$. Then there is a contradiction to continuity of $f$ (because $f(x)$ should be in $\left(\frac{1}{2},\frac{3}{2}\right)$ for $arg(z)\in(\theta-\varepsilon,\theta)$ for some $\varepsilon>0$).

Comment: You mean when $arg(z)\in(\theta-\varepsilon,\theta),f(z)\in \left(\frac{1}{2},\frac{3}{2}\right)$?

Comment: @math112358, Yes, follows from definition of continuity.

Comment: Note that by definition of continuity, we get $arg(z)\in(\theta-\varepsilon,\theta+\varepsilon)$, but the other side is not needed here.

Answer (score 1):

Note that $(f(z))^2=f(z)$ implies $f(z)=0$ or $f(z)=1$ for all $z\in\mathbb{T}$. You know $f(1)=0$, $f$ is continuous and $\mathbb{T}$ is connected. Can you conclude?

Comment: $f(T)$ is connected,but how to derive a contradiction?

Comment: @math112358 The only connected subsets of the real numbers are intervals and $f(\mathbb{T})\subseteq\{0,1\}$ by the above consideration. So either $f(\mathbb{T})=\{0\}$ or $f(\mathbb{T})=\{1\}$, but we know $0\in f(\mathbb{T})$ since $f(1)=0$, so $f(\mathbb{T})=\{0\}$. Note that continuous functions into $\{0,1\}$ being constant is a property equivalent to connectedness, see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connected_space).

Comment: Thank U so much.